# from xml to html table using jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I want to transform an xml document into an HTML table using jquery/ajax. Additionally I want to add a class to the `tr` if a condition is met. This is what I've done so far, but it doesn't work as intended: 1) the HTML table output has more `tr` and `td` than it should have and 2) the conditional classes for the tr (`.no-kids`) aren't working.
Any help would be appriciated!

JQUERY/AJAX CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "database.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xmlData) {
    $("person", xmlData).each(function(){
    var name = $(this).find("name").text(),
        kids = $(this).find("kids").text(),
            cars = $(this).find("cars").text();
    if(kids<1){
      $("tbody").append('<tr class="no-kids">');
    }else{
      $("tbody").append('<tr>');
    }             
    $("tbody tr").append('<td class="name">'+name+'</td>');
    $("tbody tr").append('<td class="kids">'+kids+'</td>');
    $("tbody tr").append('<td class="cars">'+cars+'</td>');
    $("tbody").append('</tr>');
    });
   }
  });
  $(".no-kids").css("color","red");
});
```

HTML CODE:

```
<table> 
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>KIDS</th>
            <th>CARS</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

DATABASE.XML CODE:

```
<root>
  <person>
    <name>Matt</name>
    <kids>3</kids>
    <cars>1</cars>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Jason</name>
    <kids>0</kids>
    <cars>2</cars>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Molly</name>
    <kids>1</kids>
    <cars>0</cars>
  </person>
</root>
```

Comment: ... and what do you mean by 'doesn't work as intended' ?? What errors are you getting if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery only appends whole elements, not starting/ending tags.

```
var output = '<tr' + parseInt(kids) < 1 ? ' class="no-kids">' : '>';
output += '<td class="name">'+name+'</td>';
output += '<td class="kids">'+kids+'</td>';
output += '<td class="cars">'+cars+'</td>';
output += '</tr>';
$("tbody").append(output);
```

Edit: Additionally, you need to apply the red font color in the success callback.

```
   }
  });
  $(".no-kids").css("color","red");
});
```

should be

```
     $(".no-kids").css("color","red");
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: This seems to be a very common issue when using jQuery's `.append()`

Comment: It's just a lack of understanding how the DOM works. If more people started with javascript rather than `<insert javascript library here>` it would probably happen less often. I'm also one of those developers that started with jQuery.

Comment: Actually... The syntax of adding them in that way mimics server-side code more than it does any client side code.